# Is there a way to get list of embedded objects/documents from a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, attachments

I have a Word document that is more than 100 pages. There are numerous Excel spreadsheet documents inserted as Objects within it, using the Insert > Object dialog box. Each embedded document appears as an icon in the main word document. Is there a way to get a list of all the embedded documents/objects from Word?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131787/how-to-list-all-embedded-files-from-a-microsoft-office-document-using-apache-po

Comment: Please refer to the article below: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/750-word-select-all-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question. But to have easy access to embedded objects, just open "go to" window (ctrl+g), and then select "object" and "next". You can easily navigate across objects.

More details here:
https://neuxpower.com/blog/how-to-find-embedded-objects-in-word